# DBC File with two Baud Rate definition

Tags: can-bus

I am trying to write a DBC Paser, but I never saw a DBC file with two baud rates and I wanted to ask if anyone has an example of a DBC file with two baud rates?

Comment: What have you done so far? Add this code here for better chance of getiing help

Comment: that has nothing to do with my question I am asking if anyone has seen a dbc file with two baudrate and how did it look like

Comment: Without seeing the file, I can't say for use, but the most likely scenario is that the DBC file is describing a CAN FD bus.